# A and B can be any value from 1 to 16, how many ways can A be less than B?

Tags: probability

I am trying to figure out the question in the title. Given that A and B can be any number between 1 and 16, how many ways can A be less than B?

I various combination/permutations, but I got huge numbers. The answer in the book says there are 120 ways for A to be less than B, but I kept getting numbers in the millions.

Any advice on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ can be any value from $1$ to $16,$ there are $16\times16=256$ possible choices for $A$ and $B$.

For $16$ of those choices, $A=B$.

Of the remaining $240$ choices, half have $A<B$ and half have $B<A.$

Comment: This is how I would have done it. Exploiting symmetries (here interchanging $A$ and $B$) can save a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

If $B=16$ then there are 15 possibilities for $A$ since $A$ can be any of $1,2,3,\ldots,15$.

If $B=15$, there are 14 possibilities for $A$, and so on.

Lastly if $B=2$ there is only one possibility for $A$.

So the total number of possibilities is
$$15+14+13+\ldots+1=120.$$

Answer (score 0):

If A is $1$, there are $15$ ways for B to be bigger $(2,3,...,16)$

If A is $2$, there are $14$ ways for B to be bigger $(3,4,...,16)$

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

For $A=1$ you have $15$ choices for $B$, namely $2,3,4,...,16$

For $A=2$ you have $14$ choices for $B$

Keep going and you get the total choices, $$15+14+13+...+1 =120$$